# How to get key strockes on parent control to reach child controls that host the actual binding but are not focused

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, key-bindings, inputbinding

Please let me know if I need to clarify or post more code!

I could find quite some resources on how to pass keystrokes from a child element to a parent element but not the way around.

**I explain my use case:**

I have a parent `Window` (let's call it `wndSession`) with a couple of focusable controls and a `ContentControl` which gets its content (a `UserControl`) assigned using `DataTemplate` bindings.

```
<Window.Resources>
    
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:vmLearnModule1}">
        <local:viewLearnModule1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:vmLearnModule2}">
        <local:viewLearnModule2 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:vmLearnModule3}">
        <local:viewLearnModule3 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:vmLearnResults}">
        <local:viewLearnResults />
    </DataTemplate>
    
</Window.Resources>
```

And:

```
<ContentControl Content     = "{Binding learningViewModel}"
                Name        = "contentControl"
                Grid.Row    = "1"
                Grid.Column = "1"
                Height      = "300"
                Margin      = "20, 0, 0, 0" />
```

Now each `UserControl` may have different `KeyBingind`s assigned, and as long as the focus is on the `UserControl` all works fine.

Example of bindings on a UserControl:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F1" Command="{Binding cmdResultNotKnown}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F2" Command="{Binding cmdResultAlmostKnown}"/>
    <KeyBinding Key="F3" Command="{Binding cmdResultKnown}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

My commands are defined all like this sample:

```
private ICommand _cmdTest;
/// <summary>
/// Test
/// </summary>
public ICommand cmdTest => this._cmdTest ??= new RelayCommand(param => this.doTest(), param => this.canTest);

private bool canTest => true;

private void doTest()
{
    // Some code here
}
```

**Now to the issue:**

If I click on any focusable control on the parent window `wndSession`, the `UserControl` or its currently focused child will lose Focus and a control of the parent (`wndSession`) will gain focus (ok, I'd expect that so far).

But because of this, the `UserControl` will not react to `KeyBinding`s anymore unless I click on any control of the `UserControl` first. That is not a really good UX...

**What I need is a way to:**

First i thought about something like to "bubble down" the keystroke to the child controls of `wndSession`, and especially to the `UserControl` in the `Contentcontrol`, in the event that `wndSession` does not already address the KeyBinding.

But as remarked that would cause many issues. So in order to avoid conflicts (which control can now use it's bindings, etc.) I would suppose that what is needed is to pass the keystroke to a specified target, which in my case would be the UserControl inside the ContentControl if `wndSession` could not handle the key as no binding is specified.

**In short:** have `wndSession` operate as a Router passing all unknown keystrokes (not registered by a `KeyBinding`) to a Gateway/Proxy (`ContentControl`/`UserControl`)

Then there will be only a path down the tree with little risk of conflicts. Currently I fail simulating a keystroke on the target control from parent, so that its KeyBinding can fire.

Comment: Best to avoid this method. You will have to hook so many things together. Best option is to have a helper class that handles key strokes on keyboard and hands you an event you can handle in your ViewModels, and leave the xaml out of it entirely.

Comment: Yes, that is my fear. Concerning helper classes I always am a little careful of code behind. Therefore I am wondering if there is a way to have some short of "Proxy" that catches all unhandled keystrokes and passes them to a specific control as transparently as needed. For sure "Bubbling" unhandled strokes blindly down to the Childs would cause to many issues!